# Locked Media Library Items Cannot be Read by Non-Administrator Users

Tags: media-library

Our Media Library items are behaving differently from items in our content tree when locked.

User accounts with the `Administrator` flag on can, of course, move around as usual. But any other user account (including our `Super User` type, which is allowed everything except the Administrator role) cannot unlock, edit, or even read Media Library items when they are locked by another user.

If a user tries to select a Media Library item locked by another user, nothing happens for a long time, after which we get a browser alert that says "Please wait while the Content Editor is loading." We have sat with one of our content team to observe and it's definitely not an issue of the page loading.

What could be causing this behavior?

We are on 10.1-update 2

Comment: Do you have any integration with a DAM or perhaps Azure Blob storage?

Comment: @MichaelWest We do not.

Comment: A non admin user shouldn't be able to unlock or edit the item. Are there any JS errors in the console? Any references to access result cache being cleared frequently in sitecore logs? Can user immediately access after unlocked by previous user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you described, where non-administrator users are unable to unlock, edit, or read locked Media Library items, could be caused by a few factors.

**Security Settings:** First, check the security settings for the Media Library items. Ensure that the appropriate access rights are granted to the user roles that need to perform these actions. Verify that the necessary read, write, and unlock permissions are assigned to the user roles that should have access.

**Workflow Configuration:** If you have a workflow enabled for your Media Library items, check the workflow configuration. Ensure that the workflow states and actions are properly configured, allowing users with the Super User role or other relevant roles to perform the required actions. Verify that the lock state is not preventing non-administrator users from accessing the items.

**Custom Code or Modules:** If you have custom code or modules implemented in your Sitecore instance, review them for any modifications related to Media Library item locking or access. Customizations could potentially introduce unintended behaviors or restrictions. Check for any custom pipelines or event handlers that might be interfering with the default behavior.

**Check the Sitecore Logs:** Check the Sitecore logs to see if there are any errors or warnings related to the Media Library items. This can help you identify any issues that might be causing the behavior you are seeing.

**Check the Performance Settings:** If the issue persists, it could be due to performance issues. Check the Sitecore performance settings, such as the database connection pool, to see if there are any issues there.

**Please check whether you are facing this issue on all environments or on specific environment only..**

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer. The root cause was our solution had, in fact, had its Unlock action customized, specifically to allow the `SuperUser` role to unlock as Admins do. It looked like the original author had probably decompiled the Sitecore Kernel, reproduced much of that code, and added in a check to allow SuperUser to unlock. It also happened to create some side effects, which we were able to track down.